# How do you add vertice / node information when starting from adjacency matrix?

Tags: r, igraph

This seems like a very simple thing, but I can't figure it out.
I have created a adjacency matrix, specifying which nodes are connected to which node, this is a directed graph.

```
  A B C D
A 0 1 0 1
B 0 0 0 0 
C 1 0 0 0 
D 1 0 1 0
```

I can read this into igraph with
`graph_from_adjacency_matrix(matrix)`

I also have a dataframe with specifications for every node
f.i.

```
data.frame(id = c("A", "B","C","D"), 
           color = c("red","red", "green","deathmetal black"), 
           shoesize = c(31,32,33,50))
```

How do I combine this information in 1 graph for plotting purposes?

Comment: Try to paste the data using for example `colsn = paste(id, color, shoesize, sep="_")` and add that as a `add.colnames` argument to your `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` function. So it will be something like `graph_from_adjacency_matrix(matrix, add.colnames=colsn)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge in node attribute values with `set_vertex_attr`

If you had

```
matrix <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), c("A", "B", "C", "D")))
gg <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(matrix)
```

Then you could do

```
data.frame(id = c("A", "B","C","D"), 
           color = c("red", "red", "green", "deathmetal black"), 
           shoesize = c(31,32,33,50), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
gg <- set_vertex_attr(gg, "color", dd$id, dd$color)
gg <- set_vertex_attr(gg, "shoesize", dd$id, dd$shoesize)
```

Comment: So that means every column of information has to be applied separately as an attribute? (could probably do some sort of apply function, but still)

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach is using the tidygraph package:

```
as_tbl_graph(matrix) %>% left_join(data, by=c('name'='id'))
```

According to Thomas Lin Pederson (creator of tidygraph).